# Using datetime.strftime and soutract it with timedelta

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to use datetime.now() with timedelta and soustract it so I get the time for yesterday.

```
yesterday = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") -  timedelta(days=1)
```

But when I tried to do it, it gives me this error :

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

So I tried to convert it to an int but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` return formated datetime **string**. You can find `strftime()` description [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). 
You need to substract timedelta first and then apply formatting to the result:

```
yesterday = (datetime.now() -  timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```